# Vim find and replace. How can I do it on this?

Tags: vim, replace

I have an XML file that I want to make some changes to. For example I want to open the file in Vim and run a find and replace all instances of `memory="..."` attribute to `memory="24G"` but only if the element is from `name="node-0..."`. Here is an example:

```
process name="node-0-3" numaNode="3" memory="14G" logConfig="logback-shards.xml"
process name="node-0-4" numaNode="4" memory="34G" logConfig="logback-shards.xml"
process name="node-0-5" numaNode="5" memory="44G" logConfig="logback-shards.xml"
```

replace with

```
process name="node-0-3" numaNode="3" memory="24G" logConfig="logback-shards.xml"
process name="node-0-4" numaNode="4" memory="24G" logConfig="logback-shards.xml"
process name="node-0-5" numaNode="5" memory="24G" logConfig="logback-shards.xml"
```

How can I do it in Vim?

Comment: I kind of recommend getting an XML editing tool to do this, or writing a quick script in your favorite language.. You can do it in Vim or sed if the formatting of the file is really consistent with regard to line breaks and whitespace, but this is really a job for a proper XML parser.

Comment: +1 @MichaelBerkowski, the reason is that Vim only does regular expression find/replace, and what you're trying to do will be outside the realm of regular expressions if your code is not very regular (attributes come in different orders, newlines in different places, etc.).

Answer (score 8):

```
:g/node-0/s/memory="\zs\d\{2\}\u\ze"/24G
```

Step by step:

- `:g/node-0`

  use the `:global` command to find all lines that contain `node-0`
- `s/memory="\zs\d\{2\}\u\ze"/24G`

  1. find `memory="`
  2. leave it out of the actual match by starting the match here with `\zs`
  3. match two numbers followed by a capital letter with `\d\{2\}\u`
  4. the actual match ends here with `\ze`
  5. leaving out the closing double quotes.
  6. substitute the actual match with `24G`

(edited with a more accurate pattern to suit the asker's *real* usecase)

***edit***

Using Ingo's comment:

```
:g/node-0/s/memory="\zs[^"]*\ze"/24G
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there's a line break between the attributes...  but if the formatting is consistent, should be ok.

Comment: Thanks romainl. My full line is : <process name="node-0-1" numaNode="1" memory="24G" logConfig="logback-shards.xml"> so I don't want to lose the rest of the line, how can I only edit up to memory="24G" and leave logConfig="logback-shards.xml" unchanged ?

Comment: Probably just want to convert `.*` to `.\{-}` for it to be non-greedy.

Comment: I've made it *very* specific.

Comment: ... or use `[^"]*`, which I find more expressive.

Comment: … which means "any number of anything that is not a doublequote". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `sed` one-liner if you don't want to open vim each time:

```
sed -i '/node-0/s/memory=".\{3\}/memory="24G"/' foo.txt
```

or you could use the same command from inside vim using:

```
:%!sed '/node-0/s/memory=".\{3\}/memory="24G"/'
```

Comment: Instead of redirecting the source file into itself, use `sed -i` / `--in-place`.

Answer (score 0):

If all rows are with the same format you can try this:

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>     // to get to "14G" in your first line

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> // start visual block mode

<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>     // to select [1]4G, [3]4G, [4]4G

<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>     // replace with 2